# Signing SOAP Messages in WSO2 ESB using sha-256 digest Algorithm

Tags: web-services, security, apache-axis, rampart, wso2-esb

I have an issue using rampart in wso2 ESB to sign my soap messages, i use an XML policy attached to the outgoing endpoint, this policy specifies sha-256 as the algorithm to use for the digest (AlgorithmSuite : Basic256Sha256)

The problem i have is that my generated SOAP Enveloppe uses always sha-1 for the digest... ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"

How can i do to make wso2 ESB sign a soap message using sha-256 as the algorithm method for digest ?

EDIT : XML Policy & sample request can be found here : we.tl/h7MujCEbgq

Comment: If you are using Basic256Sha256 as the AlgorithmSuite then SHA-256 has to be used for the hashing. Can you please share your complete security policy and a sample SOAP message.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, please find below the link to the security policy & the outgoing soap message (with wrong digestmethod algorithm) : http://we.tl/h7MujCEbgq

Comment: Hi, did you manage getting the files ?

Answer (score 0):

finally it was a bug in the rampart version used in WSO2, they provided us a patch to correct that.